# ¿Cómo editar dinámicamente una celda en una tabla html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel-blade

estoy generando la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
            <thead class="nombreTitulo">
                <tr>
                    @foreach($columnas as $columna)
                        <th class="verticalText">{{$columna->nombre_columna}}</th>
                    @endforeach
                    <th class="verticalText">Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($tabla as $fila)
                    <tr class="fila">
                        @foreach($fila as $columna=>$celda)
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="update fila" data-name="name" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Ingresar valor">{{ $celda['valor'] }}</a>
                        </td>   
                        @endforeach
                        <td> <!-- $fila->columna_id -->
                            <a class="deleteProduct btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="{{$celda['cid']}}">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

El problema es que la clave primaria de las celdas está formada por 4 foreign keys (idservicio, idcolumna, etc) ¿cómo formo una clave en el html que la identifique para posteriormente actualizar el valor si el usuario desea editarlo?

También me gustaría poder modificar los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: Cuando el usuario desee editarlo que quieres hacer exactamente? actualizar la base de datos? actualizar el html con js? o como?

Comment: No me quedan claras dos cosas... ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres? y ¿Qué datos muestras en la tabla? Lo de `$celda['valor']`entiendo que pone a todas las celdas de la fila el mismo dato para cada columna, así que no sé para qué es.
En cualquier caso, si quieres poner datos extra a cada `<tr>` o a cada `<td>` puedes utilizar atributos personalizados para esas etiquetas. Por ejemplo, `<tr class="fila" data-carlos-id-a="{{$fila['campo_x']}}">`
Pero vamos... eso no sería una edición dinámica *per-se* porque la generas cuando creas la página, y no dinámicamente una vez expuesta

Comment: Estoy utilizando Laravel, la idea es actualizar los datos en la base de datos. La duda principalmente la tengo en frontend. Tengo una tabla "valores" que representan las celdas. El id de cada valor está formado por varias claves. Id del servicio, id de columna, entre otras. Es decir, yo para identificar un valor (celda) en BD debo saber el id de la columna, el id del servicio y otros más ¿cómo guardo eso en html y luego lo obtengo?